# Como usar a função .replace() em uma lista de listas ou em uma lista de tuplas?

Tags: python-3.x

Sou nova em programação e nova aqui no site. Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver e por sorte vcs existem. Já tentei de tudo que estava ao meu alcance e quase consegui encontrar a solução, só que foi só quase mesmo.

Possuo o seguintes códigos que escrevi com ajuda de respostas aqui do site:

```
A=[[3, 6, 3, 8, 9, 5, 5], [8, 6, 6, 4, 7, 10, 5, 3, 3, 3],[8, 6, 4, 5, 7, 3, 3, 2], [5, 4, 4, 10,3, 3, 0], [9, 6, 3, 6, 8, 8, 1]]

def chr_remove(antigo, remover):
    nova_string = antigo
    for x in remover:
        nova_string = nova_string.replace(x, '')
    return nova_string

remove1 = chr_remove(str(A), ",")

remove2 =chr_remove(remove1," ")

remove3 =remove2.replace("[","")

remove4 = remove3.replace("]",",")

remove_final = remove4.replace(",,","")

print(remove_final)
```

Código 2:

```
A=[(3, 6, 3, 8, 9, 5, 5), (8, 6, 6, 4, 7, 10, 5, 3, 3, 3), (8, 6, 4, 5, 7, 3, 3, 2), ( 5, 4, 4, 10,3, 3, 0), (9, 6, 3, 6, 8, 8, 1)]

def chr_remove(antigo, remover):
    nova_string = antigo
    for x in remover:
        nova_string = nova_string.replace(x, '')
    return nova_string

remove1 = chr_remove(str(A), ",")

remove2 =chr_remove(remove1," ")

remove3 =remove2.replace("(","")

remove4 = remove3.replace(")",",")

remove5 = remove4.replace("[","")

remove6 = remove5. replace(",]","")

remove_final= remove6.replace(",,","")

print(remove_final)
```

Até aqui tudo bem, os caracteres indesejados foram removidos mas o primeiro problema aparece quando eu faço uma leitura dos itens da variavel A e a leitura da variavel remove_final:

```
print(len(A))
>>>5

print(len(remove_final))
>>>46
```

E o segundo problema aparece quando eu faço um loop for na variavel remove_final:

Eu gostaria que o resultado saisse assim:

```
73638955                                 
86647105333                              
86457332                                 
954410330                                
9636881
```

Mas o resultado sai assim:

```
3                                        
6                                        
3                                        
8                                        
9                                        
5                                        
5                                       
,                                        
8                                        
6                                        
6                                        
4                                        
7                                        
1                                        
0
5
3
3
3
,
8
6
4
5
7
3
3
2
,
5
4
4
1
0
3
3
0
,
9
6
3
6
8
8
1
```

Eu já tentei converter a string pra lista ou tupla mas nada muda e se eu peço pra printar como lista ou tupla o resultado também não sai como esperado:

```
print(list(remove_final))
>>>['3', '6', '3', '8', '9', '5', '5', ',', '8', '6', '6', '4', '7', '1', '0', '5', '3', '3', '3', ',', '8', '6', '4', '5', '7', '3', '3', '2', ',', '5', '4', '4', '1', '0', '3', '3', '0', ',', '9', '6', '3', '6', '8', '8', '1']                     [Program finished]

print(tuple(remove_final))
>>>('3', '6', '3', '8', '9', '5', '5', ',', '8', '6', '6', '4', '7', '1', '0', '5', '3', '3', '3', ',', '8', '6', '4', '5', '7', '3', '3', '2', ',', '5', '4', '4', '1', '0', '3', '3', '0', ',', '9', '6', '3', '6', '8', '8', '1')                  [Program finished]
```

Se eu copiar e colar o resultado em outro editor vou conseguir usar normalmente como tupla e poder fazer a contagem exata dos itens e fazer um loop for com a função `.count()` normalmente, só que eu tenho alguns milhões de dados pra analisar e não vai ter como printar, copiar e colar em outro editor.

Será que existe algum modulo que possui uma função `.replace()` pra listas de listas e listas de tuplas? Alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar este problema?

Comment: Obrigada por editar a minha pergunta @alandplm, eu tive um dia corrido e não tive nem tempo de agradecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi o objetivo, você quer, a partir lista, iterar sobre todos os seus elementos, sem vírgula. Para isto, basta corrigir a linha:

```
remove_final= remove6.replace(",,","")
```

para

```
remove_final= remove6.split(",")
```

Isso lhe retornará uma tupla com os valores de sublistas concatenados.

---

Entretanto, converter um iterável para string, remover separadores e delimitadores da string, para em seguida trabalhar com a string modificada não é a forma mais apropriada de se iterar sobre listas e tuplas, porque é de difícil compreensão por terceiros e é pouco eficiente, especialmente tendo um grande conjunto de dados.

A forma adequada de se iterar sobre listas de listas depende da estrutura que esses dados se encontram

- Se o algoritmo irá somente iterar sobre listas de listas:

```py
for sublista in A:
   texto = "".join([str(elemento) for elemento in sublista])
   print(texto)
```

- Se não se sabe quantos níveis de listas/tuplas serão encontrados, como em

```
A1 = [1, 5]
A2 = [[1,2],[5,6]]
A3 = [[[1,3],[1,2]],[[1,2],[5,6]]]
```

pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
A1 = [1, 5]
A2 = [[1,2],[5,6]]
A3 = [[[1,3],[1,2]],[[1,2],[5,6]]]

def pegaValoresRecursivamente(entrada):
    #Testa se a entrada é lista ou tupla
    if type(entrada) in (list, tuple):
        for elemento in entrada:
            for elementoInterno in pegaValoresRecursivamente(elemento):
                yield elementoInterno
    else:
        yield entrada

print("A1")
for elem in pegaValoresRecursivamente(A1):
    print(elem)

print("\nA2")
for elem in pegaValoresRecursivamente(A2):
    print(elem)

print("\nA3")
for elem in pegaValoresRecursivamente(A3):
    print(elem)
```

```
A1
1
5

A2
1
2
5
6

A3
1
3
1
2
1
2
5
6
```

com a diferença que nesse caso ele não imprimirá mais "linha por linha".

Comment: muito obrigado por tentar me ajudar! Desculpe a demora pra responder. Acabei de testar a sua resposta e infelizmente ainda não é isso que eu preciso pra resolver o meu problema. Quando eu uso a função .split() e depois uso a função len() o numero de posições não batem. Eu converti a lista em string pq foi a unica forma que encontrei pra remover os caracteres indesejados. O que eu quero como resultado final é uma tupla onde eu possa usar além da função .count(), a função set() também.

Comment: Minha linguagem é pobre e eu não me espressei da forma correta, me desculpe por te fazer perder tempo. Vc acha que eu deveria editar a pergunta ou fazer uma nova?

Comment: Essa lista de listas é o resultado de uma "fatiação" feita no resultado de uma interseção. Se eu colocar um resumo do meu código ficaria mais fácil pra vc entender? O que eu quero como resultado final é uma tupla com o mesmo numero de posições na sequência em que estavam só que sem a virgula, parenteses e colchetes pra que eu possa usar a função set() e saber o numero exato de posições que se repetem e depois fazer um loop for e usar a função .count() e uma condicional pra que se o resultado for maior que tal condição, print resultado e dessa forma economizar recursos.

Comment: vou aguardar sua resposta pra saber se faço outra pergunta ou edito esta. Muito obrigada!

Comment: Sem problemas! Acho que o recomendado nesses casos é editar a pergunta. Resumos de código, bem como descrição do propósito geral do programa são bem-vindos. Se possível acrescente também o formato/tipo inicial dos dados de entrada que serão processados

Comment: Obrigada, vou fazer isso.

Comment: da uma olhada nessa outra pergunta que eu fiz e se puder me ajude pfv https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/392513/como-usar-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-set-em-uma-lista-de-listas-ou-em-uma-lista-de-tuplas?noredirect=1#comment772911_392513