# Como usar a função set() em uma lista de listas ou em uma lista de tuplas?

Tags: python-3.x

Possuo uma uma lista de tuplas gerada com a função combinations do modulo itertools:

```py
from itertools import combinations as comb

A = range(x,xx)
B = list(comb(A,x)
```

Gerei essa lista de tuplas com a intenção de em seguida fazer uma interseção com algumas variaveis e pra isso fiz um list compression:

```
V1= x, x,x,x
V2= x,x,x,x,x
V3= x,x,x,x,x
V4= x,x,x,x,x

inter=[len(set(x) & set (y)) for x in B for y in [V1,V2,V3,V4]]
```

Em seguida fatiei o resultado da interseção com outro list compression:

```
fatia = [inter[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(inter),4)]
```

Obtive o resultado desejado mas com uma falha, quando uso a função `set()` ou `len(set(fatia))` recebo a seguinte mensagem: unhashable type: ' list '

Isso é deprimente pq eu criei o programa na intenção de saber o numero exato de padrões gerados pela interseção e não foi nada fácil pra mim aprender esses comandos.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar esse problema?

Comment: O erro acontece porque você está tentando construir um `set` de `list`, mas `list` não pode ser [hasheado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash) (que imagino que o `set` precise fazer por baixo). `set([[]])` gera o mesmo erro. Mas eu não entendi direito o que você quer, é contar as interseções do que o `combinations` retorna e o quê, exatamente?

Comment: Olá, desculpe a demora. Sim, eu quero contar quantos padrões de interseção existem no numero de combinações gerados para concluir a minha analise. Obrigada por tentar ajudar.

Comment: O objetivo do programa é obter a interseção entre `V1`, `V2`, `V3` e `V4`, para depois calcular a quantidade de elementos na interseção? O que quer dizer por "padrões gerados pela interseção"?

Comment: Se puder, edite para botar exemplos de valores possíveis em `x` em `V1= x, x,x,x`, em `A = range(x,xx)`, ainda não entendi 100% o objetivo do código, bem como o resultado que você espera obter com o programa

Comment: @danielbb, obrigada por vir aqui nessa minha pergunta. Eu quero poder usar a função set() na lista de listas gerada pelo list compression "fatia".

Comment: Os valores não são importantes, pode colocar qualquer valor ali, o que eu queria mesmo era conseguir usar a função set() para saber o numero exato de padrões existentes na lista de tuplas gerada pela formula de combinação simples (combinations).

Comment: O numero exato de padrões gerados pela interseção existentes dentro do universo gerado pela função combinations.

Comment: Entendi. E o único propósito de `set` em `len(set(fatia))` é eliminar duplicatas, certo?

Comment: @danielbb, sim exatamente isso!

Comment: @danielbb, remover as duplicatas para saber o numero exato de padrões.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe o código

```py
a = [0, 5, 2]
b = [7, 3, 2]
c = [1, 2, 3]

listaDeListas = [a, a, b, c, a, c, a, c, b]

print(len(set(listaDeListas)))
```

Seu resultado é

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interseção.py", line 9, in <module>
    len(set(listaDeListas))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Isso ocorre porque as listas, como muitos dos objetos mutáveis, não são "hasheáveis"<sup>[1]</sup>, que é um requisito para ser item de um objeto do tipo `set`<sup>[2]</sup>.

Uma possível solução, seria converter os itens para um objeto imutável. O objeto imutável "mais próximo" de uma lista, é uma tupla:

```
a = [0, 5, 2]
b = [7, 3, 2]
c = [1, 2, 3]

listaDeListas = [a, a, b, c, a, c, a, c, b]
listaDeTuplas = [tuple(i) for i in listaDeListas]
print(len(set(listaDeTuplas)))
```

retorna

```
3
```

---

Note que, nesse exemplo, itens como `a = [0, 1]` e `b = [1, 0]` são considerados distintos. Dependendo da situação, isso pode ser inconveniente.

---

<sup>[1] Chamo de tipo "hasheável" um tipo que implementa a função `__hash__`.</sup>

<sup>[2] [Documentação de `set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html): As classes de conjuntos (`set`) são implementadas usando dicionários(`dict`). Sendo assim, os requisitos para um item pertencer a um conjunto são os mesmos para as chaves de dicionário; devem implementar `__hash__` e `__eq__`</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigada @danielbb !! Era exatamente isso. Preciso estudar mais. Obrigada!

Comment: Quando eu tiver reputação te vejo no chat. Até mais.

Comment: Fico contente em ajudar. Bons estudos!